# SonarQube integration with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sonarqube

I have a remote server where I've deployed a SonarQube system, for tracking the quality of the code, and want to integrate Android Studio and Xcode with it.

For Android Studio it worked using:

```
* SonarQube plugin
* Gradle parameters (sonar.host.url, login, etc...)
```

for setting up the server and its credentials.

But for Xcode (v8.2.1) I don't know what's the best way to do this, or if any software is needed to be installed.

Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did tried that and able to get install `SonarQube` and `Sonar Scanner` in Mac Sierra. But the Objective C plugin for SonarQube requires licence from Sonar Community. I have requested for trial version of that and still waiting response from them.

You can follow below steps to full fill Prerequisites.

1. Open terminal and run below command to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```

Or if it is already installed then update it using below command

```
    brew update
```

2. Install SonarQube using below command:

   ```
   brew install sonar

   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
   ```
3. Install Sonar Scanner

   ```
   brew install sonar-scanner
   ```
4. Install Xctool

   ```
   brew install xctool
   ```
5. Install OCLint

   ```
   brew tap oclint/formulae
   brew install oclint
   ```
6. Install gcovr

   ```
   brew install gcovr
   ```
7. Set environment variables for Sonar Home

   ```
   export SONAR_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-runner/2.4/libexec
   export SONAR=$SONAR_HOME/bin
   export PATH=$SONAR:$PATH
   ```
8. Install JAVA

   ```
   brew cask install java
   ```
9. Download `.properties` file from this [Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c/master/sample/sonar-project.properties) and change project name, target and scheme
10. Copy and paste `.properties` file to your project root directory
11. Install Maven - It is required to run Objective C plugin

    ```
    brew install maven
    ```
12. Download Sonar Objective C plugin from this [Link](http://www.sonarplugins.com/objectivec)
13. Add your local host for SonarQube server. Open `sonar-project.properties` file and add below command at top of the file

    ```
    sonar.host.url=<YOUR-LOCAL-HOST>
    ```
14. In Terminal go to your project's root directory and run below command to scan project for errors and bugs.

    ```
    sonar-scanner
    ```

Comment: Thanks! And what about the free ObjC plugin found here https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c ?

Comment: I tried this free plugin but not able to install them in mac, let me know if you able to install it

Comment: Well.. In my case the SonarQube is installed in a remote linux server (not a Mac)

Comment: Then You can tell server guys to install Objective C plugin to that linux server and connect it with mac machine. Need to explore a bit that how we can connect remote SonarQube from mac machine.

Comment: You need to copy ObjC plugin into ~/sonarqube/extensions/ and restart the server

Comment: I am getting this ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati: localhost:9000 is a local server url, there should be remote server url.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati it is, but you have to provide some url for example: (129.0.0.1), just adding localhost:9000 will not work with a mac system. In case, I was unable to do so.

Comment: What if we have swift language do we need to change `sonar.language=swift`? and `sonar.swift.workspace` ?

Comment: @ZubairAhmed: Yes, most important you need to find Swift plugin for Sonar.

Comment: Qw 1> i am getting code smells but not code coverage(shows 0%) Qw2> I am not getting any bugs & vunrabilities in project. is that mean it migrated in code smells ?

Comment: You can review the report generated by Sonar for more information.

Comment: @Kampai how can we deploy to custom server `sonar.host.url=www.mywebsite.com` ?? Any steps ?

Comment: @Jack: haven't got that far, I still need to explore it.